# How to create and execute a file full of commands on Windows command prompt?

Tags: windows, command-line-interface

**Example:**
In Linux we can put the desired commands in a file and give it executable permissions. This helps us to actually run the file on the terminal and thus all the commands inside the file get automatically executed.

How to achieve this on Windows XP?

Comment: What do you mean "terminal" - telnet client, some custom remote shell, remote desktop, remote PowerShell?

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov Well, I was talking about "command prompt". Is it called something else?

Comment: I see. I just never heard/seen anyone calling command prompt  "terminal"... Usually I see "command prompt", "windows command prompt", "windows shell".

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov Well, on Linux, we usually tell people to open the terminal, and do this and that. :) So...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Same thing, but it's called a batch file, extension is `.bat`.  You can also double-click to run these.  [This site](http://www.computerhope.com/batch.htm) is a great resource.

Comment: Thanks, how to run this batch file from terminal?

Comment: `cd` to the directory where the file is, type the batch file name (with or without the `.bat` extension) and hit enter. The page I linked to goes into detail on this.

Comment: +1  Also another common extension for the same type of files is ".cmd", the same as the name of executable - cmd, which in turn provides detailed help on CMD/BAT file commands `cmd /?` and all commands support `/?` option.